# How to feed a random source with uint32s

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a 32-bit (MT19937-32, LFSR113 & LFSR88, among others) random sources in Go, but `math.Rand`'s source interface accepts `Int63()` as method.

How do we convert `uint32` to `int64` (non-negative int64, or 63-bit)

here's an LFSR88 code (some methods and consts omitted):

```
type LFSR88 struct {
    s1, s2, s3, b uint32
}

.
.
.

func (lfsr *LFSR88) Uint32() uint32 {
    lfsr.b = (((lfsr.s1 << 13) ^ lfsr.s1) >> 19)
    lfsr.s1 = (((lfsr.s1 & 4294967294) << 12) ^ lfsr.b)
    lfsr.b = (((lfsr.s2 << 2) ^ lfsr.s2) >> 25)
    lfsr.s2 = (((lfsr.s2 & 4294967288) << 4) ^ lfsr.b)
    lfsr.b = (((lfsr.s3 << 3) ^ lfsr.s3) >> 11)
    lfsr.s3 = (((lfsr.s3 & 4294967280) << 17) ^ lfsr.b)
    return (lfsr.s1 ^ lfsr.s2 ^ lfsr.s3)
}
```

Comment: `myInt64 := int64(myUint32)`

Comment: Taking the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13) should answer most of your basic syntax questions.

Comment: @Adrian: That will only give you half the random bits expected.

Comment: The question is quite obviously about how to convert a uint32 to meaningful output for a random source.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a `uint32` to an `int64` is quite simple:

```
var u32 uint32 = /* some number */
var i64 int64 = int64(u32)
```

The problem with this alone is that you'll end up with an int64 that's half 0 bits, so you probably want to combine two of them:

```
var u1, u2 uint32 = /* two numbers */
var i64 uint64 = int64(u1) + int64(u2)<<32
```

See a complete example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/YTdQytGIYms).

Comment: just off the question: Would it be better to implement math.rand's Uint64() as (uint64(r.Uint32()) << 32) | (uint64(r.Uint32()) & 0xffffffff), instead of the [default](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go#L91) if my sources comes from 32-bits?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking if 32 random bits, repeated, is better than a pseudo-random number? I don't think there's a definitive answer to that. It depends on how you're using it. The best would be to read two 32-bit random numbers from your source, and combine them.